# is mktime() using date() daylight saving aware?

Tags: php, dst, mktime

I've read through a few questions about this here on s.o. and none seem to ask or answer the question very bluntly:

```
$ts_today = mktime( 0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y') );
```

is this daylight saving aware?

if not, how do i make mktime() daylight saving aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~There's plenty of discussion of this on [the PHP site](http://uk.php.net/mktime) itself, and some useful examples.  In short, newer versions of PHP take account of DST as part of the timezone handling functionality

Comment: thanks, solved with this from the php site:
$today = mktime(12, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

Answer (score 0):

The last argument specifies whether it's DST or not. ;)

[edit] My bad, it's actually deprecated... It now depends on the timezone you specified with `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: php.net says: Note: As of PHP 5.1.0, this parameter became deprecated. As a result, the new timezone handling features should be used instead.