# Problems with finding the days between two unix timestamps

Tags: php, unix-timestamp, dst

I know there a lot of questions and answers of this already, but unfortunately I think my situation may be unique?  For some reason, the time-change seems to be making the day calculate as one day less than it should be calculating.

Here is my PHP that I was using and it was working great, until it started to overlap a start and end date that was BEFORE daylight savings, and AFTER daylight savings, respectively (FYI, this is a recent issue, since daylight savings time starts this weekend!):

```
//$lastDate and $firstDate are 2 unix timestamps with valid month, day, and year values.
//The times are irrelevant at this point, they are only meant to represent a day.

//I start by making sure these have the same time values.
$lastDate = mktime(23, 59, 59, date("m", $lastDate), date("j", $lastDate), date("Y", $lastDate));
$firstDate = mktime(23, 59, 59, date("m", $firstDate), date("j", $firstDate), date("Y", $firstDate));

//Then calculate the total number of days in between.
$totalDays = abs(floor(($firstDate - $lastDate)/(60*60*24)));
```

So again, to be clear, the above works if i'm not overlapping the daylight savings time change...

For reference:

[How to find the dates between two specified date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date)

[Actual days between two unix timestamps in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035589/actual-days-between-two-unix-timestamps-in-php)

[Finding days between 2 unix timestamps in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079814/finding-days-between-2-unix-timestamps-in-php)

And, I'm still on PHP 5.2 right now.

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I've found the following on this links:

[How to find the dates between two specified date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date)

and

[How to calculate the the interval between 2 unix timestamps in php WITHOUT dividing by 86400 (60*60*24)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751712/how-to-calculate-the-the-interval-between-2-unix-timestamps-in-php-without-divid)

```
//$lastDate and $firstDate are 2 unix timestamps with valid month, day, and year values.
//The times are irrelevant at this point, they are only meant to represent a day.

//I start by making sure these have the same time values.
$lastDate = mktime(10, 00, 00, date("m", $lastDate), date("j", $lastDate), date("Y", $lastDate));
$firstDate = mktime(10, 00, 00, date("m", $firstDate), date("j", $firstDate), date("Y", $firstDate));

//Then calculate the total number of days in between. 
$totalDays = floor($firstDate / 86400) - floor($lastDate/ 86400);
```

And it seems to work right now for the crossover of DST.  Anyone see any issues with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674918/is-mktime-using-date-daylight-saving-aware I would use new [dateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and get off 5.2 when you can.  Otherwise be sure to see `is_dst` argument of `mktime`.

Comment: @ficuscr hmmm, so DateTime is in 5.2 afterall, for some reason I thought it was only in 5.3.

Comment: A number of [fixes and improvements](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) came in 5.3 I think.  `DateInterval ` class for example.  But it is there.

Comment: @ficuscr do i need to set the timezone/object on every page load, i.e. i could do this at the same place i'm calling session_start on all these pages?

Comment: @ficuscr ok so this isn't working out well for me =).  is_dst is depreciated as of 5.1.  I can't use the DateTime class because the diff function isn't available in 5.2.  Any ideas here?

Comment: @ficuscr I added an update, check that one out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running on PHP 5.3+? A `DateInterval` fits the problem nicely.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Here's the question... I have unix timestamps to start with.  Can I use the timestamps as the argument to DateTime, i.e. `DateTime($timeStamp1)`?

Comment: @Shackrock Yes, using `DateTime('@' . $timestamp)` (notice the @ sign)

Comment: @ColinMorelli ok now you're confusing me a bit.  My timestamp should be an absolute date and time, right?  So what would 28 days have to do with anything, unless i happened to randomly be inside of the month of February?

Comment: @ColinMorelli not if you use %a in the format.  It returns total number of days.

Comment: @landons Touche, I have removed my comment.

Comment: @landons Also, I'm still on PHP 5.2 at the moment =(.

Comment: How about this to set the date and time correctly with timestamps: `$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timeStamp);`  But without PHP5.3, how can I accurately count the days between?

Comment: @landons I added an update to the question, please take a gander.

Comment: @Shackrock Hmm.. I don't know how that change accounts for DST.  `mktime()` should automatically factor it in if your server is setup correctly.  Did that fix it somehow?!

Comment: @landons UNIX timestamps are _always_ GMT. Therefore DST is not relevant. You need only worry about them when converting from a date/time to a timestamp, or back

Comment: @landons yea, that seemed to fix it.  It correctly calculates the days now (it was always 1 day short before, when crossing over this sunday, which is the time change).

Comment: @ColinMorelli well I'm starting with unix timestamps here.  They are in the DB that way.  I'm basically trying to find the most correct way to count the days _without_ the `DateTime` class.

Comment: @landons you know what, it was because of my mktime statement in conjunction with the floor on each timestamp.  Somehow, setting that time to `10,00,00` for each that are being calculated seems to do the trick... That was found in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date - although I don't completely understand why...